# apache2: disable keep-alive when header match

Tags: apache2, setenv

I want that Apache disable keep-alive for http 1.1 when a specific host header is set. But I cant figure out how it is be done, because there are really less examples on the Net to SetEnvIfExpr. What I have is this:

```
SetEnvIfExpr "%{SERVER_NAME}==home.myhome.net" nokeepalive 1
```

But Apache won't accept it with this:

> syntax error, unexpected T_OP_CONCAT, expecting '('

Any Idea?

Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a other solution to disable keep-alive on header match:

```
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_NAME}" "home.myhome.net"
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=nokeepalive:1]
```

but I also got the SetEnvIfExpr running:

```
SetEnvIfExpr "%{SERVER_NAME} == 'home.myhome.net'" nokeepalive 1
```